# Toilet with what looks like 11 inch rough-in. Do I buy 12 or 10?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

My current toilet is measuring at 11 inches even from the wall (not the molding) to the center of the bolts. Looking around I see a lot of people saying that they saw somewhere else that a 12 inch rough-in will fit, possibly with an offset flange, but I'd like a more authoritative answer if possible. My house was built in 1900, so a non-standard size wouldn't really shock me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10" unless you can move the wall back.

Comment: I don't think I have the skills to move a wall

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You could cut the floor around it and put the offset flange like Home Depot [model #889-POMPK](http://www.homedepot.com/p/3-in-x-4-in-PVC-Adjustable-Metal-Ring-DWV-Offset-Closet-Flange-889-POMPK/202313204?keyword=889-POMPK) but it will probably get to more than 12".

[image]

Comment: Might be easier to move the wall back.

Comment: No. I'v done it already on concrete floor and it wasn't sooo hard, it took just a hammer drill to dig around it and all the mess is getting covered by the toilet very nicely.